# AWS IAM policy to apply to all buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a large list of buckets and I want to grant permissions to write to a subfolder that is in all of these buckets, let's say "test-dir/". How can I write an IAM policy for a user so that this is possible, without going through all of my 100+ buckets and setting this individually?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you would want something like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "TestStatement",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*/test-dir"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The `*` represents all of your buckets.

You can test different policies on your account by using the [policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/).

More information about IAM policies [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html).